# Email : Image and Text alignment Issue

Tags: html-email

Need to show Image and Text in proper center alignment, but Images alignment seems break in cross clients. As if now, Not looking for table based solution, Please refer below DOM.

**case 1 :**

```
<span style="display:block;">
  <img src="#" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;"/>
  <a href="#" target="_blank" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; font-size:14px; line-height:normal;">text here</a>
</span>
```

**case : 2**

```
<span style="display:block;">
  <img src="#" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;"/>
  <span style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; font-size:14px; line-height:normal;">text here</span>
</span>
```

**case : 3**

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <img src="#" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;"/>
   </td>
   <td>
     <span style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; font-size:14px; line-height:normal;">text here</span>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Go with Case 3 but encase the image and span on separate tables. It will allow you more flexibility with padding (and margins) to get the alignment right. If you want a working example, please replace the image `src` above with one that is the same size as your original code please

Comment: Just keeping mind that this might not look aligned because of the line-height on the text. Often theres a greater gap at the top of a text.